# Win Forms: Using a foot switch for keyboard input?

Tags: c#, winforms, key-bindings

I am attempting to use a foot switch that will generate a keystroke when pressed.  In the software this will start a particular function.  However, when the foot switch is released, another function must be executed.
The problem is that when the foot switch is pressed, both a KeyDown and KeyUp event are sent.  When the foot switch is released there is no KeyUp event sent.

```
    private void RadioControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
          TurnOn();
    }

    private void RadioControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
          TurnOff();
    }
```

Are there any other functions or logic I can use or is this just not possible?
Thanks, Tom

Comment: What foot switch? The events are sent by that driver, *not* the application. If the driver sends a "click" when the switch is pressed, there's nothing you can do. That behaviour may be configurable though by the driver, utilities, or registry settings. You'll have to search the driver's documentation for more info

Comment: As Panagiotis says: Your best chance is the driver. If the hardware sends only peeks in the first place, then even the driver cannot fix it. It needs to go over the wire or else you're out.